# WPF - How to access method declared in App.xaml.cs?

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I access, using C#, a public instance method declared in App.xaml.cs?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
((App)Application.Current).YourMethod ....
```

Comment: It works, but I don't understand. If Application.Current == App, and they are the same type, how is this type-cast working? Thanks

Comment: Application is System.Windows.Application where else  App is inside your project derived from Application, Application.Current is of type Application, not App.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to do this right from a xaml-view ? (Like _Click="App.YourMethod"_)

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered to create a separate class to hold your application wide methods (eg. AppState.cs)?

Comment: This is a better approach, but I wanted to know how to see the stuff declared in App.xaml.cs. Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious what you had in mind with this suggestion. You still need a place to store it. Where better to store an application-wide method than in your application class? How else would you be able to access it from any window?

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a static property in your `App` class with `new` modifier like so:

```
public static new App Current => Application.Current as App;
```

This way you can access your method like so:

```
App.Current.YourMethod()
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649174/new-keyword-in-property-declaration-in-c-sharp) answer about new modifier on SO.