# "new" keyword in property declaration in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I've been given a .NET project to maintain. I was just browsing through the code and I noticed this on a property declaration:

```
public new string navUrl
{
  get 
  {
    return ...;
  }
  set
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I was wondering what does the `new` modifier do to the property?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It hides the navUrl property of the base class. See [new Modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx). As mentioned in that MSDN entry, you can access the "hidden" property with fully qualified names: `BaseClass.navUrl`. Abuse of either can result in massive confusion and possible insanity (i.e. broken code).

Comment: The `new` modifier does not cause this behavior, it only tells the compiler you did it intentionally so it won't show a warning message.

Answer (score 18):

`new` is hiding the property.

It might be like this in your code:

```
class base1
{
    public virtual string navUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class derived : base1
{
    public new string navUrl
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Here in the derived class, the `navUrl` property is hiding the base class property.

Answer (score 8):

This is also documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152(VS.80).aspx).

Code snippet from msdn.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void DoWork() { }
    public int WorkField;
    public int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public new void DoWork() { }
    public new int WorkField;
    public new int WorkProperty
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}    

DerivedClass B = new DerivedClass();
B.WorkProperty;  // Calls the new property.

BaseClass A = (BaseClass)B;
A.WorkProperty;  // Calls the old property.
```

Comment: Your code snippet clarifies the hiding concept well, however the `new` modifier does not cause this behavior, it only tells the compiler you did it intentionally so it won't show a warning message.

Comment: Then what does cause this behavior? Usually A.WorkProperty would call the property of the derived class, since A references a derived object, regardless of the references type.

Answer (score 3):

Some times referred to as `Shadowing` or **[method hiding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28VS.71%29.aspx)**; The method called depends on the type of the reference at the point the call is made. [This might](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_polymorphism.html) help.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx

Look at the first example here, it gives a pretty good idea of how the `new` keyword can be used to mask base class variables