# How to create custom TextBox control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to perform `Trim()` method on each `TexBox` control on my page, before value is returned. I dont' want to hard-code the same code for each TexBox control, I want to do it in more elegant way.

I've found made the following class

```
namespace System.Web.UI.WebControls
{
    public partial class TrimmedTextBuox : TextBox
    {
        private string text;
        public override string Text
        {
            get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? text : text.Trim(); }
            set { text = value; }
        }     
    }
}
```

but it fails, while debuggind the compiler doesn't get inside `get{}` and `set{}`.

After that, I created a `UserControl` item, but it must be deriverd from `System.Web.UI.UserControl`, not `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` to get it work (there's an exception which points to that)

So, how can I do that ?

Comment: How are you calling your `TrimmedTextBuox` ? I'm afraid that your not using the custom control that you've created!

Comment: Try this `public new string Text` instead of `public override string Text`

Comment: IMO 'set' should be trimmed like text = value.Trim() not 'get'.

Comment: @alfoks I've tried it already, nothing happened

Comment: It seems correct. Check  Thiago Vinicius comment. Do you have a `TrimmedTextBuox tbox = new TrimmedTextBuox();` somewhere in your code?

Comment: hmm, I thought that partial class should fit for standard <asp:TextBox> control

Comment: @Tony `partial` is used when you want to define the class in more than one plcaes (2 files for example). You need to use the class you created, not `TextBox`

Answer (score 3):

First you have to register your control in your .aspx page like that:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="customControls" Namespace="WebApplication.Custom.Controls" Assembly="WebApplication"%>
```

Then you can call it using the markup

```
<customControls:TrimmedTextBuox  ID="txtTrim" runat="server"/>
```

Plus you don't have to create another "text" property in your custom `TextBox`. Instead, it can be done like that:

```
namespace WebApplication.Custom.Controls
{
    public class TrimmedTextBuox : TextBox
    {
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {                
                return base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                    base.Text = value.Trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will trim recursively all text boxes before inserting.

```
 public static void trimRecursive(Control root)
    {
      foreach (Control control in root.Controls)
      {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            var textbox = control as TextBox;
            textbox.Text = textbox.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            trimRecursive(control);
        }
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    trimRecursive(Page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution to your problem is to hide the Text property of your base class by using `new` keyword. sample code...

```
public class TrimmedTextBox : TextBox
{
    public new string Text
    {
        get
        {
             var t = (string) GetValue(TextProperty);
            return t != null ? t.Trim() : string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

For more info about how new keyword with property works refrer to this SO [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649174/new-keyword-in-property-declaration-in-c-sharp)