# What methods should be override to make proper inheritance of `ObservableCollection`

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, observablecollection

I want to make a class that joins `Table` and `ObservableCollection` functionality. So I wrote:

```
public sealed class ObservableTable<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, ITable<T> where T : class
{
    private Table<T> _table;

    public Expression Expression => _table.AsQueryable().Expression;
    public Type ElementType => _table.AsQueryable().ElementType;
    public IQueryProvider Provider => _table.AsQueryable().Provider;

    public new IEnumerable<T> Items => _table;
    public new T this[int index] => _table.ElementAt(index);
    public new int Count => _table.Count();

    public ObservableTable(ref DataContext dbContext)
    {
        _table = dbContext.GetTable<T>();
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    } 

    public void InsertOnSubmit(T entity)
    {
        _table.InsertOnSubmit(entity);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add));
    }

    public void Attach(T entity)
    {
        _table.Attach(entity);
    }

    public void DeleteOnSubmit(T entity)
    {
        _table.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove));
    }
}
```

But despite `_table` object properly gets all the records from database, when I cast my class as `ObservableCollection` the collection is empty. What should I override to get it working? Aren't `Items` and `Count` properties enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the underlying `ObservableCollection<T>` ***is*** empty. You're redirecting the indexer and Count properties of `ObservableTable<T>` to return values from your table, and you're hiding the original property implementations through `new` , but the actual collection, the internal storage that the `ObservableCollection` uses,  never gets populated.

If you use the `ObservableTable<T>` as is, everything works. But as soon as you cast it to `ObservableCollection<T>`, the original implementation of the indexer and count properties will get called, and they will try to retrieve values and count from the internal storage.

Comment: I want to make `ObservableTable` to be `ItemsSource` of `ListView`. So it's not possible?

Comment: Yes you can. Implement INotifyCollectionChanged and INotifyPropertyChanged, instead of inheriting from ObservableCollection<T>. This is enough for any class to participate in the updating of (list-) controls in WPF. Google for "INotifyCollectionChanged example" and you're bound to find some implementation examples.

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding the properties, you are "reintroducing" them in your class and **hiding** the properties of the `ObservableCollection<T>`. Check [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649174/new-keyword-in-property-declaration-in-c-sharp).

So if you access the `Count` property as `((ObservableCollection<T>)instanceOfObservableTable).Count`, you actually get the hidden `Count` property of the base class, not your "reintroduced" property. You can access your property only like that: `((ObservableTable<T>)instanceOfObservableTable).Count`.

The `Count` property is not virtual, so you cannot override it.

I would suggest yout to implement both the `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces in your class, so you can use it as an observable collection.

Comment: As I wrote in other comment, I want to make `ObservableTable` to be `ItemsSource` of `ListView`. Is there any possibility to do that?